# Comparing dates, looking for the next instance of a specific time

Tags: c#, datetime, nunit, nservicebus

Based on my unit-test I'm trying to calculate when the next instance of 0400 hrs are and return this;

```
public void when_given_a_date_i_should_return_next_time_of_day_that_equals_04_hrs()
{
    var dateTimeNow = new DateTime(2012, 6, 11, 14, 22, 0);
    var dateTimeExpected = new DateTime(2012, 6, 12, 4, 0, 0);

    Assert.AreEqual(dateTimeExpected, t.CalculateIncremental(dateTimeNow));
}
```

The point of CalculateIncremental is to publish a message with nservicebus every 24 hrs, at exactly 04:00 am using RequestUtcTimeout. This again to trigger some functionality.

Comment: Okay... so what's the question?

Comment: Oh, jees. Sorry. So used to colleagues reading my method-names, thus understanding what it does. Method should return the next time of day that equals 04 am- need the algorithm to calculate this :)

Comment: But you haven't said what you've tried, and what problems you've run into. Just giving a unit test and implying "Implement this for me please" isn't really the way the site works...

Comment: I know that Jon. I'm sorry if my question is not clear and I do not want you guys to 'implement this for me'. I'm simply looking for good practice and advise on the topic.

Comment: So what *have* you tried, and what concerns you about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private static DateTime GetNext4AM(DateTime input)
{
    var result = new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, 4, 0, 0);

    if (result > input)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return result.AddDays(1);   
    }
}
```

Should return the next occurrence of 4 AM, which can be on the same day (if the input is earlier than 04:00) or the next. However:

> The point [..] is to publish a message with nservicebus every 24 hrs, at exactly 04:00 am using RequestUtcTimeout. This again to trigger some functionality.

You should use a scheduler for that, like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) or simply the Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Check the hour of `dateTimeNow`, if it's less than 4, return its date and 4AM as the hour. If it's 4 or more, return the date of the next day, and 4AM as the hour. Decide what you want to do with 4:00:00 - either this day or the next one.

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new DateTime();
var dateTimeExpected = new DateTime(now.GetFullYear(), 
    now.GetMonth(), now.GetDay(), 4, 0, 0);
if (dateTimeExpected.CompareTo(now) > 0)
    dateTimeExpected = dateTimeExpected.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: This does not work if the 'next' 04:00 is today (for example, if the current time was 02:00.